# Graphics lagging every second

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 18.04, multiple-monitors

I just recently got a 2k monitor (with a second 1080p monitor) and my graphics are lagging for a short period of time, every second.

- Happens on Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04
- I'm using Nvidia driver 390
- And using Nvidia GeForce GTX 760
- Does not happen when I boot up to Windows
- Does not happen when I only use the 2k monitor and not the 1080p
- Continues to happen when I only use the 1080p monitor and not the 2k
- Did not happen when I was using two 1080p monitors
- Continues to happen when I downscale the 2k monitor to be 1080p

It lags about every second, like a heart beat. It's just the graphics, because audio and other processing are continuing fine while the screen lags. When I restart, the lagging starts out slow (maybe 0.1 seconds every second) and it progressively gets worse until it lags for probably 0.25 seconds every second.

I've tried reinstalling the drivers, reinstalling to different drivers, upgrading to 18.04, and pretty much anything else I could find online.

Answer (score 1):

Wow. After a week of searching for a solution, it ended up just being a loose HDMI cord. I have no idea how it caused the behaviors described above. Perhaps Satan possessed the cord. Once I plugged it all the way in, it worked like normal, no problem.

The moral of the story, kiddies, is to check your HDMI cords before posting on AskUbuntu.

Comment: I have heard of this before causing problems.  Good troubleshooting!  +1